# Fix Microsoft Excel and Powerpoint crash in macOS Sierra 10.12

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, crash, microsoft-powerpoint

Does anyone know how to fix MS Office crashing upon launch in macOS Sierra (10.12)?

The MS Office version is 15.26 and for some reason, MS Word works fine. I have just clean installed macOS 10.12 and then installed Office. I also have a clean install of Yosemite in another partition and the same version of Office works flawlessly there.

Any ideas? See below part of the crash report.

```
Microsoft Error Reporting log version: 2.0

Error Signature:
Exception: 
Date/Time: 2016-09-22 22:58:38 +0000
Application Name: Microsoft Excel
Application Bundle ID: com.microsoft.Excel
Application Signature: XCEL
Application TimeStamp: 0x5593ed3d
Application Version: 15.11.2.150701
Crashed Module Name: merp
Crashed Module Version: 15.11.2.150701
Crashed Module Offset: 0x00003365
Blame Module Name: MicrosoftSetupUI
Blame Module Version: 15.11.2.150701
Blame Module TimeStamp: 0x5593ee93
Blame Module Offset: 0x0000000000013dc1
StachHash: ffff9322
Application LCID: 1033
Extra app info: Reg=en Loc=0x0409
Crashed thread: 0

... 

Microsoft Application Information:
Error Reporting UUID: 156112AD-1ABE-455D-B097-71443AF951DD
ULS UUID: 9AA6FE04-1888-4D1E-BBFB-E82549DA2D10
Time from launch: 0 hours, 0 minutes, 1 seconds
Total errors on this client: 10
```

Comment: I have the same exact issue.

Comment: Same problem over here

Comment: I have the same crash also in Word

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the updater did not work for me. However, I did a manual update to change my MS Office to 64-bit (rather than 32-bit) and this worked. I found the download here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3187505

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it was resolved as soon as I updated office. Could it be that you have disabled the microsoft updater? If you run the updater it should update office to the latest version and the crashes should stop.

[Microsoft Updater Download](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3133674)

Answer (score 0):

- Had the same issue.  Spent all day trying to figure it out.

I have VMWare Fusion installed and had Office 2010 installed in Fusion.

Uninstalled Office 2010 from Windows ( in Fusion ).

Deleted the related Office 2010 apps that showed up under the /Applications folder in OS X Sierra

Uninstalled Office 2011 for Mac ( deleted the office 2011 apps from the /Applications folder in OS X Sierra )

in the user's Library folder ...//Library/Containers folder I deleted all the com.microsoft folders

in the User's Library folder ...//Library/Group Contains/ folder I deleted UBF8T346G9.Office  UBF8T346G9.OfficeOsfWebHost  UBF8T346G9.ms  ( anything related to Microsoft )

If you do not use Outlook like I don't use outlook on my mac, you can go to the User's ....//Library/Application Support/ folder and delete the entire Microsoft folder

Emptied the trash folder

restarted the computer

did a spotlight search for Microsoft to make sure NO Microsoft applications lingered.

Downloaded and re-installed Office 2016 for Mac.

Bam!  it worked.

I figured this out by trial and error.  Hope it helps someone.